# Nesting if statements inside a while loop - C shell

Tags: while-loop, tcsh

I have to write a tcsh script for unix that pulls values from every other line in a text file, compares them and  decides if you should buy(1), sell(-1) or do nothing(0).  Basically a simple stock profit calculation.  I think I have all the logic right, but when I run the script I get a "while syntax error" and it never executes.  I have the full script below, is it not possible to nest statements in a while loop with unix?  If so any suggestions how to do this?

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set lineNum='wc -l testcase.txt'
set i=1
while ($i<$lineNum) 
   set prices='sed -n '$lineNump' testcase.txt'
   set arr=( $price )
   set j='echo ${#arr}'
   set price=0
   set x=0
   set y=0
   set k=0
   while ($k < $j)
      set a=arr[$k]
      set str=""
      if ($a>$price)
      then
          str="$str 1"
          price=$((price-a))
      else if($a<$price)
      then
          str="$str -1"
          price=$((price+a))
      else if($a==$price)
      then
          str="$str 0"
      fi
      str="$str $price"
      if ($str=='sed -n'('expr $lineNum+1'p)' testcase.txt')
      then
          x=$((x+1))
      fi
      y=$((y+1))
    end
lineNum=$((lineNum+2))
end
echo $x/$y
```

Comment: some indentation will really help to improve readability of your code and may result in faster response  :)

Comment: I think you are using `'` instead of `\`` in your code, guessing you want to use command substitution.

Comment: Use `#!/bin/tcsh -f`, not just `#!/bin/tcsh`.  The `-f` avoids sourcing the user's `.cshrc` and `.login` files, which saves time and avoids dependencies on an individual user's setup. (This does not apply to bash or sh scripts, where `-f` has a different meaning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script appears to be a mixture of `tcsh` and `bash` syntax.

As Mark's answer says, the `then` keyword has to be on the same line as the `if` (unless you use a backslash to splice two lines, but there's not much point in doing that).

For a variable assignment, the `set` keyword is not optional; this:

```
str="$str 1"
```

is a syntax error in csh/tcsh (it will probably look for a command whose name starts with `"str="`.) Write that as:

```
set str = "$str 1"
```

Note that you can *optionally* have spaces around the `=` in a `set`. tcsh's syntax is a bit messed up:

```
set foo=bar   # ok
set foo = bar # ok
set foo= bar  # ok
set foo =bar  # error: "Variable name must begin with a letter."
```

The `x=$((x+1))` syntax is specific to bash and related shells.  tcsh uses `@` for arithmetic assignments:

```
set x = 42
@ x ++        # sets $x to 43
@ x = $x * 2  # sets $x to 86
```

If you have a choice, I suggest writing your script to use bash rather than tcsh (you're about halfway there already).  Its syntax is much more regular.

The classic rant about csh/tcsh programming [can be found here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the end statement correspoding to the first while.
You are also using fi instead of endif.
The "then" keywords need to be on the same line as the "if" they belong to.